# Google glass GDK - Error opening camera

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm developing an app for Glass using GDK but I'm having problems starting the camera intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_FROM_CAMERA);
```

And the error is:

```
11-24 19:21:30.925: E/StrictMode(591): class com.google.glass.camera.ApiTakePictureActivity; instances=2; limit=1
11-24 19:21:30.925: E/StrictMode(591): android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class com.google.glass.camera.ApiTakePictureActivity; instances=2; limit=1
11-24 19:21:30.925: E/StrictMode(591):  at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I just started camera development and got to the same problem. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: No. I am still having problems. The photo is being taken and saved, but app crashes and onActivityResult is not being called. Try using "output" extra with the value of the desired location of the photo file when starting the intent, and use the FileObserver just before creating the intent, ignoring onActivityResult

Comment: On my case it doesn't crash but I can't access the file, the same checked the file on adb and it exists. I'll try specifying the file name as you suggest. Thanks!

Comment: So weird, I'm trying specifying the EXTRA_OUTPUT parameter but doesn't seem to work either. That file is never created, the parameter seems to be ignored:

filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/DCIM/Camera/temp.jpg";
        Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, filename);

Comment: changed the filename for the Uri but nothing. So weird something so simple doesn't work

Comment: I haven't had time to test it last days, but last time I tried it I was using an Uri and it gave me an Exception, so I suppose it is trying to use it. I'll let you know if I manage to do it using a String. BTW, the exception was: 
Key output expected String but value was a android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri. The default value <null> was returned.
12-02 00:47:16.776: W/Bundle(563): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
12-02 00:47:16.776: W/Bundle(563): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: Never got it to work, I decided to switch to a custom made camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've solved this. The Exception is still shown, but it works perfect. Using the extra "output" doesn't work since it is not used by the camera intent. OnActivityResult doesn't work either since it is not being called...
What I've done is to ignore onActivityResult and to use a FileObserver pointing the Camera folder and waiting for an event when a new file is created.

```
final File photoFolder=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "DCIM/Camera");
fileObserver = new FileObserver(photoFolder.getAbsolutePath(), FileObserver.CREATE) 
        {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(int event, final String path) 
            {
                if(event == FileObserver.CREATE)
                {
                    fileObserver.stopWatching();
                    // Do whatever
                }
            }
        };
        fileObserver.startWatching();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the constant from android.provider.MediaStore when creating your Intent:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_FROM_CAMERA);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it will change anything since the value of that constant is "android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"

Comment: Are you declaring an object of type android.hardware.Camera and calling camera.open()? If so, take these calls out. I was able to reproduce the error above by simply including these. My code works without them.

Comment: No, I'm not declaring any Camera object, I'm just using the above two lines :S

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have more than one instance opened

```
instances=2; limit=1
```

Comment: I have just one place where I start that camera intent :S